# Combining grep() family of functions with a conditional if statment

Tags: r, regression

I'm using LASSO as a variable selection method for my analysis, but there's one particular variable that I wish to ensure is contained in the final formula. I have automated the entire process to return the variables that LASSO selects and spits them into a character string formula e.g. formula = y~x1+x2+x3+... However there is one variable in particular I would like to keep in the formula even if LASSO does not select it. Now I could easily manually add this variable to the formula after the fact, but in the interest of improving my R skills I'm trying to automate the entire process.

My thoughts to achieve my goal so far was nesting the grep() function inside an ifelse() statement e.g. `ifelse(grep("variable I'm concerned with",formula)!=1, formula=formula,formula=paste0(formula,'variable I'm concerned with',collapse="+"))` but this has not done the trick.

Am I on the right track or can anyone think of alternative routes to take?

Comment: Apologies if this is the wrong forum to post this question, I'm relatively new to the Stack Exchange family

Comment: Hi @jclifo8, AdamO's answer is what we usually do. Assuming that the variable you wanna keep is the last. Can you fit = glmnet(...,penalty.factor=c(1,....0)) and then check whether fit$beta[nrow(fit$beta),] has any zeros

Comment: @StupidWolf could you elaborate a bit on what exactly i'm checking with the code ```fit$beta[nrow(fit$beta),]```? I did as you described ```fit <- glmnet(X,Y,alpha=1,family = "gaussian",lambda = cvfit$lambda.1se,penalty.factor = c(1,...,0))``` and then checking ```fit$beta[nrow(fit$beta),]``` I am returned a 0

Comment: Sorry I get it now. You ran it with one lambda. Ok yes, it is dropped in the end

Comment: There's something weird going on.. Can you include this code you use to run the glmnet in your post, and dput(head(X,10)) and dput(head(Y,10)) ?

Comment: LASSO is still penalizing my variable of interest, even with the added penalty.factor argument. Sorry, I'm not quite understanding your last comment. Are you saying I should include dput(head(X,10)) and dput(head(Y,10)) into my glmnet() function?

Comment: what I meant was to give more information about your problem. If you do both of those, you can have them as part of post. And you should provide the codes used to run the glmnet.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation

> penalty.factor -  Separate penalty factors can be applied to each
>   coefficient. This is a number that multiplies lambda to allow
>   differential shrinkage. Can be 0 for some variables, which implies no
>   shrinkage, and that variable is always included in the model. Default
>   is 1 for all variables (and implicitly infinity for variables listed
>   in exclude). Note: the penalty factors are internally rescaled to sum
>   to nvars, and the lambda sequence will reflect this change.

So apply this as an argument to glmnet using a penalty factor of 0 for your "key coefficient" and 1 elsewhere.

Formula is not a character object, but you might want to explore `terms.formula` if your goal is to edit formulas directly based on character output. `terms` objects are really powerful ways of doing variable subset and selection. But you really need to explore it because the formula language was not really meant to be automated easily, rather it was meant to be a convenient and readable way to specify model fits (look at how difficult SAS is by comparison).

```
f <- y ~ x1 +x2
t <- terms(f)

## drop 'x2'
i.x2 <- match('x2', attr(t, 'term.labels'))
t <- t[, -i.x2] ## drop the variable

## t is still a "terms" object but `lm` and related functions have implicit methods for interpreting as a "formula" object.

lm(t)
```

Comment: so the penalty factor can just be a vector of 1's and 0's? i.e. if my variable of interest is 10th in my model.matrix() input, then I can write ```penalty.factor <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)``` and then include the penalty factor argument into ```glmnet(X,Y,alpha=1,family="gaussian", penalty.factor = penalty.factor)```

Comment: I have tried the steps detailed in my comment above, and it did not keep my variable of interest

Comment: @jclifto8 you probably need to follow the site rules of supplying a minimal working example

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are attempting to adjust character value of formula to a formula object which will not work given the different types. Instead, consider [`stats::update`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/update.formula.html) which will not add any terms not already included as a term:

```
lasso_formula <- as.formula("y ~ x1 + x2 + x3")

# EXISTING TERM
lasso_formula <- update(lasso_formula, ~ . + x3)
lasso_formula
# y ~ x1 + x2 + x3

# NEEDED VARIABLE
lasso_formula <- update(lasso_formula, ~ . + myTerm)
lasso_formula
# y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + myTerm
```

Should formula be a character string, be sure to use `grepl` (not `grep`) in `ifelse`. And do not assign with `=` inside `ifelse` as it is a function itself returning a value itself and not to be confused with `if...else`:

```
lasso_formula <- "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3"    

lasso_formula <- ifelse(grepl("myterm", lasso_formula),
                        lasso_formula,
                        paste(lasso_formula, "+ myterm"))    

lasso_formula 
# [1] "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + myterm"
```

Comment: thank you for the response. my "formula" is actually a character string, and i do not convert it into a formula object until subsequently plugging in said LASSO-generated formula i.e. ```model <- glm(as.formula(formula),data=....)``` so my thought was that I could adjust the character value of my formula before my model step

Comment: Why not have this as intermediate step? Char -> Formula -> Model. Again, you avoid any needs for conditional logic with `update`. Nonetheless, see edited solution when formula is a character value.